# Reformat Code with Custom Language (Dust.js)?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, pycharm, dust.js

I'm trying to use the automatic Reformat Code option in my JetBrains IDE (PyCharm Pro 4.5), but it won't work for my *.dust templates. I tried using the custom dust plugin (https://github.com/yifanz/Intellij-Dust), which adds syntax highlighting.

Is there really no way for the IDE to use something like my HTML Code Style settings on a different file extension or for custom definitions to be created on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a way to define generic style definitions. The "Intelli-Dust" plugin developer would need to add them to the plug-in. or yo would need to add your own plug-in. The reason being is that defining code style formatting rule is fairly complex.

Comment: Ahh, found confirmation here: [Custom Language Code Style](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Developing+Custom+Language+Plugins+for+IntelliJ+IDEA#DevelopingCustomLanguagePluginsforIntelliJIDEA-CodeStyleSettings)